# Uninstall application programmatically on jailbroken iDevice

Tags: ios, installation, uninstallation, ipa

I would like to know if it is possible to uninstall an application on a jailbroken iPhone/iPad via the commandline (preferably by bundlename).
ideviceinstaller can do so (even on unjailbroken devices) but since the solution I need has to work on all common operating systems and ideviceinstaller does not work reliable/properly on Windows I thought: Why not put this task on the mobile device itself.

Uninstalling it manually is not an option as this tool will handle installing and uninstalling >500 apps a day and doing so will take hours if done by hand.

Also the apps have to get installed properly, so copying the *.app directory into /var/stash/Applications and respringing is also not what I'm looking for. They have to get installed and uninstalled by Apple's own MobileInstallation service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete an application downloaded from an App Store you can delete it in a folder (/private)/var/mobile/Applications/) where apps are installed from the App Store or synced. (In /Applications/ you will find Camera, Safari, etc...)

To do so, you will first have to find the "hashed" name of the app in that folder.

Comment: I thought about that but I heard from another developer that doing so will result in iOS not recognizing the app as being deleted and a white icon will remain on the SpringBoard indefinitely (and perhaps more sideeffects will occur).

Comment: Tested it, it leaves a non-working icon that a restart of SpringBoard fixes. No other problems found with this method yet, even though it feels wrong.